# How to Summarize datagridview values based on Uniqe ID's c#

Tags: c#, dictionary, datagridview

[image]

I am trying to get a summary of my DataGridView using the c# Dictionary. but it only supports a key and value.

```
ID   |  Weight
301  |   75Kg
302  |   80Kg
302  |   80Kg
301  |   43Kg
304  |   600Kg
```

The Results Should be like this in a DataGrid View:

```
ID  |  Qty |  Weight
301     2     118Kg
302     2     160Kg
304     1     600Kg
```

I am only able to get the ID and Qty like above.

```html
 Dictionary<string, KeyValuePair<int, decimal>> dic = new Dictionary<string, KeyValuePair<int, decimal>>();

                string cellValue = null;
                decimal weight = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i <= selecteddgv.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
                {
                    if (!selecteddgv.Rows[i].IsNewRow)
                    {
                        cellValue = selecteddgv[1, i].Value.ToString();
                        weight = Convert.ToDecimal(selecteddgv[5, i].Value);
                        if (!dic.ContainsKey(cellValue))
                        {
                            dic.Add(cellValue, new KeyValuePair<int,decimal>(1, weight));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            dic[cellValue] +=  new KeyValuePair<int,decimal>(1, weight));

                        }
```

i have tried this but when it comes to update in the else block it triggers an error at the '+='

and please help me how to display it into a datagridview after using the KeyValuePair.

Comment: I dont think SQL tag is needed. Please remove it

Comment: Question not clear?

Comment: Are you trying to modify the data in memory or do you want a fitting SQL query? Show us how you currently get your data into your grid

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking only in SQL then this is simple:

```
select id,count(*), sum(Weight)
from [table]
group by id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well there is nothing to do with the dictionaries that they take only one key and a value. As a 'not-ideal' solution, you can create a nested dictionary. The key in this dictionary will hold the ID's and the value will be a

```
KeyValuePair<int, string>
```

that "int" is "Qty" and "string" is "Weight"

Your over-all dictionary object will be an object made out of

```
Dictionary<int, KeyValuePair<int, string>> myDict = new Dictionary<int, KeyValuePair<int, string>>();
```